# String.Format: why is this code not working?

Tags: c#, string.format

I'm getting FormatException with this piece of code

```
string yyyy = OPENING_DATE.Substring(0, 4);
string mm = OPENING_DATE.Substring(4, 2);
string dd = OPENING_DATE.Substring(6, 2);
ncbaccount.Date_Opened = string.Format("{1}/{2}/{3}",dd,mm,yyyy);
```

PROBLEM: OPENING_DATE is like '20140317'

SOLUTION: I want a string like '17/03/2014'

Thanks

Comment: Format placeholders begin at `{0}`, not `{1}`.

Comment: Change `"{1}/{2}/{3}"` to `"{0}/{1}/{2}"`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace {1}/{2}/{3} with {0}/{1}/{2} as it begins at 0.

Ex:

```
string yyyy = OPENING_DATE.Substring(0, 4);
        string mm = OPENING_DATE.Substring(4, 2);
        string dd = OPENING_DATE.Substring(6, 2);
        ncbaccount.Date_Opened = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dd, mm, yyyy);
```

Comment: chosen as answer cos it answered the original question. Implemented Sergey's solution though cos its kinda neater

Answer (score 11):

Instead of splitting your date string, then formatting it and parsing, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.parseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and provide format of date string:

```
DateTime date = 
     DateTime.ParseExact(OPENING_DATE, "yyyyMMdd", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: @oliverdejohnson This will then let you hold the date in a proper `DateTime` type and go on to convert back to a string with better formatting options available.

Comment: also use .ToString() for above, as you want the date in string format

Comment: ok many thanks...I like the idea.in converting back to the required string format i added this below your code: `string.Format("{0:dd/mm/yyyy}",date);`

Answer (score 0):

Only change this line

```
string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", dd, mm, yyyy);
```

More over you should be using DateTime Functions to parse date and times.